# How to set Method Break point/Diamond shaped breakpoint in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints, intellij-14

Not able to find the options to add the method breakpoint in my IntelliJ IDEA.

It shows me circular shape breakpoint in my IDE. I want to change it to method breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Did you try putting the breakpoint on the method instead of the class like shown on your screenshot?

Comment: Ohh Yes, It is working now..Thanks  : )

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the breakpoint is set on a class, not on a method. It will help if you actually set it on a method instead.

Comment: Yes,It is working now...Thanks